# Redshift COPY - err_reason Invalid value err_code 1216

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

After attempting to run my Redshift `COPY` command:

```
copy my_schema.my_table
from 's3://my-bucket/my_json_file.json.gz'
iam_role 'my_role'
JSON 'auto';
```

I get the following

```
[XX000] ERROR: Load into table 'my_table' failed.  Check 'stl_load_errors' system table for details.
```

So when querying

```
select raw_line, err_code, err_reason
from stl_load_errors;
```

I get:

```
+----------------------------+--------+--------------+
|raw_line                    |err_code|err_reason    |
+----------------------------+--------+--------------+
|.......c..my_json_file.json |1216    |Invalid value.|
+----------------------------+--------+--------------+
```

which doesn't really help me to understand what the problem is. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

As I'm loading GZIP compressed data I had to inform the COPY command of such compression format with the following

```
copy my_schema.my_table
from 's3://my-bucket/my_json_file.json.gz'
iam_role 'my_role'
GZIP
JSON 'auto';
```